# pagination in custom theme view in custom module

Tags: paging

> I have a custom module and output of that will be shown using custom
>   theme view and i want to put the pagination in the result. I tried all
>   the things but pagination could not shown on page. here is my file:

**form_example.module**

```
<?php
function form_example_permission() {
  return array(
    'submit form_example' => array(
      'title' => t('Submit form_example'),
      'description' => t('Submit the form_example form'),
    ),
    'access form_example submissions' => array(
      'title' => t('Access form_example submissions'),
      'description' => t('Access the form_example submissions'),
    ),
     'access form_example search' => array(
      'title' => t('Access form_example search'),
      'description' => t('Access the form_example search'),
    ),
  );
}
function form_example_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['form-example'] = array( //this creates a URL that will call this form at "examples/form-example"
    'title' => 'Employess Entry Form', //page title
    'description' => "A form to submit the employee's data.",
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'access arguments' => array('submit form_example'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', //this is the function that will be called when the page is accessed.  for a form, use drupal_get_form
    'page arguments' => array('form_example_form'),

      );

 $items['form-submissions'] = array(
    'title' => t('List'),
    'page callback' => 'form_example_submissions',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'access arguments' => array('access form_example submissions'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  $items['form-list'] = array(
    'title' => t('List'),
    'page callback' => 'form_example_list',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'access arguments' => array('access form_example search'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

function form_example_form($form, &$form_state) {

$form['empcode'] = array(
  '#weight' => '0',
  '#required' => '1',
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Employee Code'),
);
$form['empname'] = array(
  '#weight' => '1',
  '#required' => '1',
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Employee Name'),
);
$form['empemail'] = array(
  '#weight' => '2',
  '#required' => '1',
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Employee Email'),
);
$form['empdesignation'] = array(
  '#weight' => '3',
  '#required' => '1',
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Employee Designation'),
);
$form['file'] = array(
  '#weight' => '4',
  '#type' => 'file',
  '#size' => '30',
  '#title' => t('Employee Photo'),
);
 $form['submit'] = array(
     '#weight' => '5',
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );

return $form;

}

function form_example_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  /*if (!($form_state['values']['price'] > 0)){
    form_set_error('price', t('Price must be a positive number.'));
  }*/
 // print('<pre>'.print_r($form_state['values'],1).'</pre>');
  //die();
 $file = file_save_upload('file', array(
    'file_validate_is_image' => array(),
    'file_validate_extensions' => array('png gif jpg jpeg'),
  ));
  if ($file) {
    if ($file = file_move($file, 'public://')) {
      $form_state['values']['file'] = $file;
    }
    else {
      form_set_error('file', t('Failed to write the uploaded file the site\'s file folder.'));
    }
  }
  else {
    form_set_error('file', t('No file was uploaded.'));
  }
}

function form_example_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
   $file=$form_state['values']['file'];
  unset($form_state['values']['file']);
  $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
  file_save($file);
 // drupal_set_message(t('The form has been submitted and the image has been saved, filename: @filename.', array('@filename' => $file->filename)));


 $fe_id = db_insert('form_example')
        ->fields(array(

          'empcode' => $form_state['values']['empcode'],
          'empname' => $form_state['values']['empname'],
          'empemail' => $form_state['values']['empemail'],
          'empdesignation' => $form_state['values']['empdesignation'],
          'empphoto' => $file->filename,
        ))
        ->execute();
        drupal_set_message(t('Successfully added'));

}
function form_example_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'form_example_function' => array(
      'variables' => array('rows' => NULL),
    ),
    'form_example_template' => array(
      'variables' => array('rows' => NULL),
      'template' => 'form_example_template',
    ),


  );
}

/* view the form submissions*/
function form_example_submissions()
{
  $results =  db_query("Select * from {form_example}");
   $rows = array();
  foreach($results as $result)
  {
    $rows[] = array(
        $result->fe_id,
        $result->empcode,
        $result->empname,
        $result->empphoto,
        $result->empemail,
         $result->empdesignation,
      );

  }
  return theme('form_example_function',array('rows' => $rows));
}
/*function theme_form_example_function($variables)
{
  print_r($variables);
//$output ="<h2>".print_r$variables."</pre></h2>";
/*  foreach ($variables as $result)
  {

    $output = "<h2><pre>".print_r($result)."</pre></h2>";
  }
return $output;
 $output = '';

    foreach($variables['rows'] as $row) {
        foreach($row as $values) {

          print_r($values);
         $output .= "Empcode: " . $values . "</br> ";
         // $output .= "EmpName: " . $values[1] . " </br>";
        //$output .= "Emphot: " . $values[2] . "\n";
        }
    }
    return $output;

}*/
function theme_form_example_function($variables)
{
    $output = '';
   $search_form =drupal_get_form('form_example_search_form');
    $output = '<div class="block" >'.drupal_render($search_form).'</div>';
    $output .= '<div style="clear:both;padding:30px;" ></div>';


   //print_r($variables);
    foreach($variables['rows'] as $row) {
      //  echo $path;
      // $output .= "Empcode: " . (isset($row[1]) ? $row[1] : "--") . " ";
      //  $output .= "EmpName: " . (isset($row[2]) ? $row[2] : "--") . " ";
      //  $output .= "Emphot: " . (isset($row[3]) ? $row[3] : "--") . "<br>";   

$img_url = 'public://'.(isset($row[3]) ? $row[3] : "--");  // the orig image uri
$style = 'medium';  // or any other custom image style you've created via /admin/config/media/image-styles



     $output .= '<div class="views-row"><div class="do_featured">
  <div style="position: relative;" class="do_image"> 
            <div class="field field-name-field-thumb-image field-type-image field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item "><img  src="'.image_style_url($style, $img_url).'" ></div></div></div></div>
  <div class="do_title">
    <span>    <div class="field"><div class="field-items"><b>'.(isset($row[2]) ? $row[2] : "--") .'</b></div></div>
 <div class="field"><div class="field-items">Emp Code: &nbsp;</div><div class="field-items">'.(isset($row[1]) ? $row[1] : "--") .'</div></div> 
 <div class="field"><div class="field-items">'.(isset($row[4]) ? $row[4] : "--") .'</div></div> 
 <div class="field"><div class="field-items">'.(isset($row[5]) ? $row[5] : "--") .'</div></div> 



      </span> 
   </div></div></div>';



    }

    return $output;
}
function form_example_list(){
    $search_form =drupal_get_form('form_example_search_form');
    $content = '<div class="block" >'.drupal_render($search_form).'</div>';
    $content .= '<div style="clear:both;padding:30px;" ></div>';

    $query = db_select('form_example', 'pd');
    if(isset($_GET['empname']) && $_GET['empname'] != ''){
        $query->condition('pd.empname', '%' . db_like($_GET['empname']). '%','LIKE');
    }
    if(!empty($_GET['empcode'])){
        $query->condition('pd.empcode', '%' . db_like($_GET['empcode']). '%','LIKE');
    }
    if(isset($_GET['empdesignation']) && $_GET['empdesignation'] != ''){
        $query->condition('pd.empdesignation', '%' . db_like($_GET['empdesignation']). '%','LIKE');
    }
    $query->fields('pd');
 //    $query->extend('PagerDefault')->limit(1);
   //$query->limit(10);
    //$table_sort = $query->extend('TableSort')->orderByHeader($header);
    //$pager = $table_sort->extend('PagerDefault')->limit(10);

    $results = $query->execute();
   $rows = array();
  foreach($results as $result)
  {
    $rows[] = array(
        $result->fe_id,
        $result->empcode,
        $result->empname,
        $result->empphoto,
        $result->empemail,
         $result->empdesignation,
      );

  }
//  $limit =1;
//  pager_default_initialize(count($results), $limit, $element = 0);
//$pager = theme('pager',array("quantity"=>5));
//return theme("form_example_function",array("rows"=>$rows ,"pager"=>$pager));


  return theme('form_example_function',array('rows' => $rows));
 //return $content;
}
function form_example_search_form($form, &$form_state){

    $form['#method'] = 'get';
    $form['#token'] = FALSE;
    $form['#form_build_id'] = FALSE;
    $form['#form_id'] = FALSE;
    $form['empname'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Employee Name'),
        '#attributes' => array( 'maxlength' => '128', 'size'=> '30'),
        '#prefix' => '<div class="form-inline views-exposed-form"> <div class="views-exposed-widget">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
        '#default_value' => isset($_GET['empname'])?$_GET['empname']:'',
    );
    $form['empcode'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Employee Code'),
        '#attributes' => array( 'maxlength' => '128', 'size'=> '30'),
        '#prefix' => '<div class="form-inline views-exposed-form"> <div class="views-exposed-widget">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
        '#default_value' => isset($_GET['empcode'])?$_GET['empcode']:'',
    );
    $form['empdesignation'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Designation'),
        '#attributes' => array( 'maxlength' => '128', 'size'=> '30'),
        '#prefix' => '<div class="form-inline views-exposed-form"> <div class="views-exposed-widget">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
        '#default_value' => isset($_GET['empdesignation'])?$_GET['empdesignation']:'',
    );
    //views-exposed-widget

    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#attributes' => array( 'name' => ''),
        '#prefix' => '<div class="views-exposed-widget">',
        '#suffix' => '</div></div>',
        '#value' => 'Apply',
     );  

    return $form;
}
?>
```

> **form-list** is my url which shows the filter and when i submit the
>   search filter database content shows and i want to show pagination
>   there.

Comment: I'll save you the trouble (because there really is just too much code here) - ditch this and grab Entity Form module. Recreate the form, by attaching fields to the Entity Form. Create a view display with Views, problem solved.

Comment: Please, please review the Drupal API. There are a lot of things that simply aren't necessary above. Check your SQL queries against injections and never pass $_GET directly to them.

Comment: the thing is i have a custom view with pager is not attached

Comment: i have tried alot of things but nothing could happedn

Comment: That is not a custom view from Views. That is HTML using view generated markup and classes. Not the same.

Comment: then what to do please help am stuck here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45943/discussion-between-sumit-aggarwal-and-kevin).